# How to assign special folder icons in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, icons, thunar

I inadvertently deleted my *Pictures* folder on my linux box running XFCE / Thunar and, after restoring from the trash bin, the folder icon is plain with no *camera* on it.

**How do I get the folder icon back?**

In folder properties I just find how to add emblems to the bottom left corner of the icon but it's not the same thing.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Hmm... have you tried restarting your session? (I.e. logged out and in again)  Could be XDG-related.

Comment: Nope, didn't work...

Comment: Nor switching between icon sets works, Pictures acts as a normal folder while Videos, Documents, Music etc switch according to theme...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs` contains the line:

```
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
```

Then restart Thunar.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks a lot, but, apart from asking on SE, how's a mortal supposed to know about these magic? It really drove me nut...

Comment: I searched Google for [xfce picture folder icon], which lead me to [this Gentoo forum page](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-923976-start-0.html), where someone quoted the Gentoo installation messages that mention `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.  I looked in that file and found the `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` line.  I tried playing with it and that seemed to cause the behavior you saw.

Comment: Another method that I used was to search the `/etc` and `/home/.config` directories for the string `Pictures`, under the assumption that it was somehow configurable (since yours managed to stop working).  Since that's a fairly unique capitalization, it pretty quickly pointed me towards the `user-dirs.dirs` file either in `/home/.config` or `/etc/xdg`.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, I searched Google for the same terms too but had no luck, maybe I did not pay enough attention. Unluckily to me it was not possible to search the string `Pictures` as it was somehow removed, good idea though. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more complete **$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs** for anyone that doesn't have the file at all:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```